# Ruby on Rails: will_paginate is not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

If I click the next or previous link it doesn't go to the next or previous page.

All posts are on same page, but there are links next, previous at bottom.

In PostsController:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

in posts/index:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts%>
```

Where is the problem with will_paginate?

Comment: Can you post (1) the SQL that's actually being executed from your development log, and (2) the URL that "Next" and "Previous" point to, so we can see if it's wired up correctly?

Comment: Clicking next,previous link i get url like that, http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?page=2 or http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?page=1, but all 17 posts are in same page, clicking those links does nothing.

Comment: Sanity check: are there more than 15 posts in your db right now? :)

Comment: Yes, there are 17 posts and all posts are there in http://0.0.0.0/posts/index and in http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?page=2 and in http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is causing your error, but ordering should be done outside of will_paginate.

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

This is how it should be done in Rails 3.

I've also had trouble setting the per_page parameter within the controller.  You could try setting it in the model instead.

```
class Post
  self.per_page = 10
end
```

Comment: That didn't work, i did @posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC') , i also added 
  self.per_page = 10 in model that also didn't work.

Comment: would you post all the code in your controller method and the view?

Comment: also, would you run the query in the console and post the sql.
 To do so, add to_sql at the end of the query. Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').to_sql

Comment: Where would i type that line, in rails console ? Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').to_sql

Comment: I got this, "SELECT  \"posts\".* FROM \"posts\"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 15" for Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => 2).order('created_at DESC').to_sql

Comment: open the console with the commmand "rails c", then at the prompt run the query.  The console is a great place to troubleshoot.
Your query should return an array of posts.  Also try running Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').size to see how many posts it's returning

Comment: what is params[:page] here on console ?

Comment: Yes, from rails c i got 15 posts from , Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => 1).order('created_at DESC')

Comment: Your query is looks correct then. The problem is probably some where else.  If your view is showing more than 15 posts, you may be loading the posts from another query.  If you post your code, i'll take a look at it.

Comment: It's done, i was using wrong variable in posts/index.html.erb view.

Answer (score 2):

You have to order before paginate, 
so, change it to

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating to `will_paginate , '3.1.7'` solved my issues